# How to remove unnecessary Bootstrap 5 components to keep CSS smaller?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use Bootstrap 5 in my website template. However, I only need the 12 grid system and Navbars. I do't need other components such as buttons, accordions etc.

Is there any way to download or build a Bootstrap 5 CSS with only selected components to keep my stylesheet smaller and less cluttered?

I tried web based SASS compiler from a website called https://bootstrap.build
but I couldn't find any option to remove unnecessary components